# GetRecordIDs syntax and S-Controls?

Tags: s-control

What's going on in this syntax? It's being launched from a button on an account

```
{!INCLUDE($SControl.custom__c)}

    var accountId = '{!Account.Id}';
    var accountIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Account)};
    var zipCodes = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Cstom_c)};

    var params = "";
    var error = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does nothing by itself. The only possible side effect is that there is an S-Control being imported, which may include code beyond what goes on here (see Setup > Develop > S-Controls for that code).

The remaining five non-blank lines simply assign values to local variables. There are no functions that *do* anything directly other than assignments, and since those variables are wrapped inside a function, I'm pretty sure they can't really be accessed from outside the function, either.

From my experience, I would say that this was an attempt to do something that was abandoned half-way through (or earlier, more like 1/3 of the way through). I say this because there are no function calls that lead outside of the current scope (e.g. nothing from the S-Control is called), no calls are going out, nothing is modified in any way at all.